# How to clean dirty data of dataframe (imported from csv file), filter nums and transfer into the float type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There's a csv file, contains numbers, "***", "(X)"￼ and NAN.
Then I use pd.read_csv() to import this into dataframe.
see: [import data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIIhO.png)

but all values in df are "str" type. see: [desc data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJCa2.png)

I want to filter the num and transfer them into float type and for the others to NAN.
Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Please post a picture of some of the sample data in the dataframe, your current script, what the output of the current dataframe is (not a photo), and a output of what you are looking for. In the future please use a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question format.

Comment: I already posted two pictures in my origin question. Please have a see.

Comment: Make it easy for people to help you. This includes presenting your data in a format that people can copy and paste. Screenshots are inconvenient because sample data must be copied/typed out manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `NaN` filter of `pd.read_csv()`. For each column you can specify different values that should be considered NaN. In your case this should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', na_values={'HC04_VC03': '(X)', 'HC04_VC04': '***'})
```

Pandas will then automatically choose a fitting dtype for your data. In this case you get the desired float columns. You can also specify the data type as you read in the csv file using the parameter `dtype = {'GEO.id2': np.int64, 'HC04_VC04': np.float64, 'HC02_VC05': np.float64}` or any other valid dtypes of your choice. Use this option with care since setting the dtype will throw an error if the data cannot be converted to the desired type, e.g. if you don't get rid of all `'***'` strings first.

Alternatively, you could read in the csv file without specifying data types, and then convert the columns after using [pd.to_numeric](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html). For example,

```
df['GEO.id2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['GEO.id2'], errors = 'ignore') # values that can't be converted to integer types will be left alone
```

In the documentation, there are other methods for handling data that can't be converted.